# Java FTP over TLS/SSL (FTPS- Implicit) Server in Java - Several Error

Tags: java, client, implicit, ftps

I am trying to connecting a server with FTPSClient (true implicit), port 990, and it seems the connection is ok, but it says that the file PDF inside cannot be found.

```
     String protocol = "TLS"; // TLS / SSL 
    boolean isImpicit = true; 
    int timeoutInMillis = 3000; 

    FTPSClient client = new FTPSClient(protocol, isImpicit); 

    client.setDataTimeout(timeoutInMillis); 
    client.addProtocolCommandListener(new PrintCommandListener(new PrintWriter(System.out))); 

    try 
    { 
        int reply; 

        client.connect(server, port); 

        client.login(user, pass); 
        client.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE); 

        client.execPBSZ(0); 
        client.execPROT("P"); 

        System.out.println("Connected to " + server + "."); 

        reply = client.getReplyCode(); 

        if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply)) 
        { 
            client.disconnect(); 
            System.err.println("FTP server refused connection."); 
            System.exit(1); 
        } 

        client.listFiles(); 

        boolean retrieved = client.retrieveFile(Constantes.DIRECCION_FTP_PDF_FACTURAS + nombre_factura, new FileOutputStream(Constantes.DIRECCION_FTP_LOCAL_DESCARGAS + nombre_factura)); 

    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    { 

        if (client.isConnected()) 
        { 
            try 
            { 
                client.disconnect(); 
            } 
            catch (IOException ex) 
            { 
                ex.printStackTrace(); 
            } 
        } 
        System.err.println("Could not connect to server."); 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
        return; 
    } 
    finally 
    { 
        System.out.println("# client disconnected"); 
        client.disconnect(); 
    } 

}
```

The error I got is java.io.FileNotFoundException
I tried writing the full path since C:\ , and without it, but nothing works.

Anybody can help me?

Thanks.

EDIT: IT WORKS NOW!

Comment: Did you first try to use a good old ftp client (FTPS compatible of course...) like linux `ftp` or FileZilla from Windows to see what the FTPS server actually presents?

Comment: Of course, is a REAL server working.

Comment: Now the PDF is downloading, but with 0 KB.

Comment: If the file if found but cannot be downloaded it could be a problem of active vs passive FTP mode.

Answer (score 0):

The path "Program Files" contains a space and maybe FileInputStream does not manage to resolve it properly.
May give it a try to put your folder to "C:/Temp/" and test it again.

Where does this FileNotFoundException happen exactly?

Comment: I edited my code, now its working but bad. It seems that PDF is downloaded but with 0 KB.

Comment: This looks like a problem that other ppl also had already:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7558732/ftpclient-download-file-failed-the-retrievefile-method-replycode-550